# Apache Spark Unit Test not running in command line but runs in eclipse

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, maven-surefire-plugin

I have written an Unit test for our project which uses Apache Spark with Java 8. In test i am creating a local SparkContext to read a Parquet file in resource folder and calculate the results. It works fine in eclipse. But when i run test command on command prompt it fails with error:
**Command:**

```
mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -DTest=MyTestClass -T8
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 55, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: parquet/common/schema/ColumnPath
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.getPath(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:584)
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:549)
        at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:527)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:435)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:390)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:157)
        at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
```

As you know in POM file we add the dependency as provided, do you think Maven is not able to resolve the error because of this or i am doing it wrong.

I also copied all jar dependencies in lib folder and set the context with "**extraClassPath**" still it failed.

```
conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName(MyTestClass.class.getName());
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\sparlibs");
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\sparlibs");
```

Then i tried adding the lib folder in the maven-surefire-plugin but it also failed.

```
            </plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                        -Xms256m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <testSourceDirectory>/src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>C:\Users\user\sparlibs</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

POM File is like:

```
<properties>
    <cdh.version>cdh5.5.2</cdh.version>
    <hbase.version>1.0.0-${cdh.version}</hbase.version>
    <spark.version>1.5.0-${cdh.version}</spark.version>     
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-orbit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Really looking to find answer.

Comment: What is in the `<dependencies>` block of the POM? Also, why are you running `eclipse:clean` and `eclipse:eclipse` on the command line? I would expect to see something like  `mvn clean install -DTest=MyTestClass -T8` for a plain Maven command.

Comment: @user944849 I have added the dependencies above. Also i am still getting same error when i execute command >mvn clean install -DTest=MyTestClass

Comment: Please explain why all of the dependencies have scope `provided`. Are you deploying the completed application into a container that provides the dependency jars? If not, try removing the scope and see what happens.